# sympy.plotting.plot strange xlabel position

Tags: python, plot, sympy

When setting 'xlabel' to a string value in a plot statement in sympy, the label is placed at the far right of the graph. If the label is not set in the program, and i click on the checkmark and set the label there, it's positioned in the middle of the X axis.

here's an example:

```
from sympy import sin
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot

x = symbols('x')
y = sin(x)

p1=plot(y,(x,0,7),xlabel="x data")
p2=plot(y,(x,0,7))
```

figure 1 has the X-axis label to the far right. if you open figure 2, and click the checkmark at the top to set the label interactively, it places it correctly in the middle of the axis.

any way to instruct the program to centre the label?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sympy's implementation of matplotlib for plotting is convenient, but rather limited compared to the full matplotlib functionality. If you want to change the label location on the axis you need to access the backend `ax` object from your plot. Here's how to do that:

```
fig = p1._backend.fig
ax = p1._backend.ax

ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,0)

fig.savefig('test.png')
```

[image: image showing axis label centered below graph]

This will save your graph as `test.png` (see picture). If you are using a gui like jupyter you can also show the plot by calling `fig`, but in command line interfaces this will not work. I do not know any convenient way to show the plot (like `p1.show()` would) using only the sympy interface (so without importing `matplotlib.pyplot`). If you know how to use matplotlib however you can manipulate both the figure and axis objects in far more detail.

Comment: Seems to no longer work. At least for 1.8.

Comment: After trying to access the plot options in SymPy 1.8 unsuccessfully I found that the label string can be aligned by pre- or appending blank spaces.